# id reference is showing error and not giving import option

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-developer-api

my image View id is showing an error, probably not importing... this is my xml for Image View...

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/abc"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
        tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars"
        android:contentDescription="TODO" />
```

and this is MainActivity where in glide, image view id is not accepting...

```
val jsonObjectRequest =  JsonObjectRequest(
            Request.Method.GET, url, null,
            {response ->
                Glide.with(this).load(url).into(abc);
            },
            { })
```

these are my imports...

```
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.android.volley.Request
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide
```

please assist me to resolve that...

Comment: That was kotlin synthetic which is deprecated now.  Use View Binding or Data binding instead to access the views .

Answer (score 0):

Can do this using the traditional way, assuming you are not using Kotlin Synthetics or View Binding:

```
 val imageView = view.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.abc)
```

Then do this at where you want to use the abc image view like this:

```
 Glide.with(this).load(url).into(imageView);
```

If you want to use the Kotlin Synthesis method, can follow this [link](https://antonioleiva.com/kotlin-android-extensions/) here to add in the imports but it is not recommended anymore as it is deprecated to give way for [View Binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding).

Comment: that 'view' is showing warning

Comment: Remove the view if you are using activity, only add it if you are using fragment